# How could I remove adjacent duplicate value without using a loop?

Tags: python

Like the given list is
l=[4,2,3,4,4,5]

Turn into
l=[4,2,3,4,5]

I try to create an empty list to store the value but it is hard to compare if the two elements are equal with no loop

Comment: itertools.groupby

Comment: There is no way to do this "without a loop". You need some sort of loop to check all elements adjacent to each other

Comment: I could fix it using loop but I try to think of whether using map() and reduce() can solve it or not

Answer (score 0):

to store every element only once is same like a set.
you can use following code.

```
l=[2,3,4,4,5]
l=list(set(l))
l.sort()
```

it will give your expected output

Comment: This could create unexpected order

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary which only keeps unique values as its key

```
l=[2,3,4,4,5]

list(dict.fromKeys(l))
```

Comment: Would it be made into a key? I just want to check the adjacent values are equal or not

Comment: if removing duplicates is the goal then the outer list function converts the keys back to a list, but if you want to specifically check the adjacent values, you will need a loop. You probably want to reframe your topic then.

Comment: Do you have any idea to use map() or reduce() to fix it?